# C++ dll throwing assertion faliure

Tags: c#, c++, assertions

I have a program written in C# that consumes a dll written in C++. I have the source for that but changing that is out of scope. There are two files of the type .pak and .jrn that get saved in the application. However the location of these files are configurable. If I choose to save it in a local location (somewhere on the hard drive of the machine running my C# code) it works just fine. However, when I try to configure the system to store the files in a remote machine, I get Assertion Failure error in C++.

This is really urgent. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What happens if you map the remote location to a drive letter with `net use`?

Comment: So what specific line in the C++ code gives the assertion failure? Post exact code, by editing your message.

Comment: Hi Benoit, I tried using Network drive to map the shared folder path. That didn't work.

Comment: Hi Martin, I am not sure, how can I debug the C++ code from the Visual Studio. I am consuming the dll that got generated out of these C++ code. However, I found the function it is failing.

Comment: You should edit the source into the question so you can format it. It's not obvious to me where the assertion is there; you should tell us exactly what line and what other information it gives you. But ultimately I think you'll have to debug the code. Does debugging it not just work? Do you have the .pdbs for the C++ library? If not, but you do have the source, then rebuild that yourself with debugging information enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you are configuring `pakDir`, but not `jrnDir`. So my guess is that `jrnDir` points to an invalid file path on the remote machine.

Comment: Hi Martin, The files are getting saved to the remote shared folder. However it is throwing Assertion Failure Exception as I mentioned before.

Comment: Then you have been posting the wrong code. You really need to find out what function (at least) causes the assertion error; better to find out what line.